# why options request long time spend to responding in asp.net web api

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

When it comes to the application, the system's response speed is good and logical. After a short time is not sent to the application, the first request OPTIONS to the server has a 12 second interval.
In the conditions that I set for the Plesk panel for idle timeout 30 minutes, then it should not be the reason for this slowdown.

Comment: Because  if there is no request for 20 minutes, worker process (w3wp.exe) will stop to save the server resources, see https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/brijmishra/posts/12-tips-to-increase-the-performance-of-asp-net-application-drastically-part-2

Comment: I made the above changes. This problem is caused by interruptions between requests of up to 5 minutes

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about "servers", I only think that the problem can be caused by this, 5 minutes looks like very short :(